# 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in wp8 app

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8

I would like to create a service in wcf and consume that service in wp8 app, I created a service for listing details,in WCF Testclient i'm getting records but while using that service in wp8 app i'm getting Exception like

"System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException"

How can i solve this any ideas?

Comment: Service1Client proxy = new Service1Client();
            proxy.FindEmployeeCompleted += new EventHandler<FindEmployeeCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_FindEmployeeCompleted);

            proxy.FindEmployeeAsync(s,null );

Comment: I refered this link only "http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/urmimalapal/creating-a-windows-phone-7-application-consuming-data-using-a-wcf-service/"

Answer (score 1):

First build a working client to this service from desktop C#. Then compare the outgoing of this working client to the output of wp8. Also turn on [WCF trace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/05/18/601458.aspx) on the server to see extra error details.

Comment: yes,its working in desktop applications, but why exception in windows phone app

Comment: compare the soap sent by both working and non working clients

Comment: i'm new in wcf,can you please tell me, how to get soap of clients

Comment: one way is to log the message on the server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx another way is to use fiddler on the android device http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid